# force directed graph in d3 with collapsable property

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to use D3 for a drawing network graph which can show a specific node at first. Then when clicking on that node, it will expand other nodes.

I use this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/9wvmL8q8/) and I have a little changes on that code here, it just shows two of the four nodes. I can't figure out why it doesn't show all nodes and why it loses the collapsable property.

```js
var root;
var COLLAPSE_LEVEL = 1;
var dataset = {
  nodes: [
    {
      id: 1708498,
      name: "Chieh-Jen Wang",
      w: 88
    },
    {
      id: 1710977,
      name: "jan",
      w: 88
    },
    {
      id: 32944442,
      name: "mike",
      w: 88
    },
    {
      id: 2761079,
      name: "ana",
      w: 88
    }
  ],
  edges: [
    {
      from: 1708498,
      to: 1710977,
      w: 1
    },
    {
      from: 1708498,
      to: 32944442,
      w: 3
    }
  ]
};

var width = 960,
  height = 1000;

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout
  .force()
  .size([width, height])
  .on("tick", tick)
  //gravity(0.2)
  .linkDistance(height / 13)
  .charge(function(node) {
    if (node.type !== "ORG") return -2000;
    return -30;
  });

// build the arrow.
svg
  .append("svg:defs")
  .selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter()
  .append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 12)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 9)
  .attr("markerHeight", 5)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .attr("class", "arrow")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var json = dataset;

var edges = [];
json.edges.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.id === e.from;
    })[0],
    targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
      return n.id === e.to;
    })[0];

  edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: e.Value
  });
});
var username = "Chieh-Jen Wang";
var userid;
var othernode = [];
for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length; i++) {
  if (json.nodes[i].name === "Chieh-Jen Wang") {
    userid = json.nodes[i].id;
    json.nodes[i].collapsing = 0;
    json.nodes[i].collapsed = false;
  } else {
    json.nodes[i].collapsing = 1;
    json.nodes[i].collapsed = true;
    othernode.push(json.nodes[i]);
  }
}

var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.selectAll(".node");

force.on("tick", function() {
  // make sure the nodes do not overlap the arrows
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    // Total difference in x and y from source to target
    diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

    // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
    pathLength = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

    // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
    offsetX = (diffX * d.target.radius) / pathLength;
    offsetY = (diffY * d.target.radius) / pathLength;

    return (
      "M" +
      d.source.x +
      "," +
      d.source.y +
      "L" +
      (d.target.x - offsetX) +
      "," +
      (d.target.y - offsetY)
    );
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});

update();

function update() {
  var nodes = json.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });

  var links = edges.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  link = link.data(links);

  link.exit().remove();

  link
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  node = node.data(nodes);
  node.exit().remove();

  node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "node " + d.type;
    })
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  node
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("id", function(d) {
      return d.id;
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      d.radius = 10;
      return d.radius;
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d.id === userid) {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length; i++) {
          json.nodes[i].collapsing = 0;
          json.nodes[i].collapsed = false;
        }
      }
    });
  // return a radius for path to use
  //make lable for circles
  // node.append("text")
  //.attr("x", 0)
  // .attr("dy", ".35em")
  // .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  //  .attr("class", "text")
  //  .text(function(d) {
  //   return d.name
  // });

  // On node hover, examine the links to see if their
  // source or target properties match the hovered node.
  node.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    link.attr("class", function(l) {
      if (d === l.source || d === l.target) return "link active";
      else return "link inactive";
    });
    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(d.name);
  });

  // Set the stroke width back to normal when mouse leaves the node.
  node
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      link.attr("class", "link");

      // we hide our tooltip on "mouseout"

      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    })

    .on("click", click)

    // we move tooltip during of "mousemove"
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip
        .style("top", event.pageY - 30 + "px")
        .style("left", event.pageX + "px");
    });

  function click(d) {
    if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
      var inc = d.collapsed ? -1 : 1;
      recurse(d);

      function recurse(sourceNode) {
        //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
        edges.forEach(function(l) {
          if (l.source.id === sourceNode.id) {
            l.target.collapsing += inc;
            recurse(l.target);
          }
        });
      }
      d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
    }

    update();
  }
}

function tick() {
  link
    .attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

  node
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });

  t.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  }).attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });
}

var toggleColor = (function() {
  var currentColor = "black";

  return function() {
    currentColor = currentColor == "black" ? "red" : "black";
    d3.select(this).style("fill", currentColor);
  };
})();
var tooltip = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip");

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle");

circles.forEach(function(c) {});
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
    "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  fill: black;
}
.node:active {
  fill: lightgray;
}
.node .text {
  fill: white;
}

.ORG .circle {
  fill: #1d3649;
}

.EMR .circle {
  fill: #b2d0f5;
  stroke: #5596e6;
  stroke-dasharray: 3px, 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.EMR .circle:hover {
  fill: #5596e6;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link.active {
  stroke: darkblue;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.arrow {
  fill: #666;
}

.arrow.active {
  stroke-width: 0 !important;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.doubled {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey only two nodes are comming deu to the in the update function d.colapsing == 0 is retur false here d.colapsing value is 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo with your data and collapsable property

```js
var dataset = {
  "nodes": [{
    "id": 1708498,
    "name": "Chieh-Jen Wang",
    "w": 88
  }, {
    "id": 1710977,
    "name": "jan",
    "w": 88
  }, {
    "id": 32944442,
    "name": "mike",
    "w": 88
  },{
    "id": 2761079,
    "name": "ana",
    "w": 88
  }],
  "edges": [{
    "from": 1708498,
    "to": 1710977,
    "w": 1
  }, {
    "from": 1708498,
    "to": 32944442,
    "w": 3
  }]
}

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
.size([width, height])
//gravity(0.2)
.linkDistance(height / 6)
.charge(function(node) {
  if (node.type !== 'ORG') return -2000;
  return -30;
});

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
  .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
  .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
  .attr("id", function(d) {
  return d;
})
  .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
  .attr("refX", 12)
  .attr("refY", 0)
  .attr("markerWidth", 9)
  .attr("markerHeight", 5)
  .attr("orient", "auto")
  .attr("class", "arrow")
  .append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var json = dataset;

var edges = [];
json.edges.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return n.id === e.from;
  })[0],
      targetNode = json.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.to;
      })[0];

  edges.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: e.Value
  });
});

for(var i=0; i<json.nodes.length; i++) {
  json.nodes[i].collapsing = 0;
  json.nodes[i].collapsed = false;
}

var link = svg.selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.selectAll(".node");

force.on("tick", function() {
  // make sure the nodes do not overlap the arrows
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    // Total difference in x and y from source to target
    diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

    // Length of path from center of source node to center of target node
    pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

    // x and y distances from center to outside edge of target node
    offsetX = (diffX * d.target.radius) / pathLength;
    offsetY = (diffY * d.target.radius) / pathLength;

    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + (d.target.x - offsetX) + "," + (d.target.y - offsetY);
  });

  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
});

update();

function update(){
  var nodes = json.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });

  var links = edges.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .start();

  link = link.data(links)

  link.exit().remove();

  link.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

  node = node.data(nodes);

  node.exit().remove();

  node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
    return "node " + d.type
  });

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
    d.radius = 30;
    return d.radius
  }); // return a radius for path to use 

  node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .text(function(d) {
    return d.type
  });

  // On node hover, examine the links to see if their
  // source or target properties match the hovered node.
  node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    link.attr('class', function(l) {
      if (d === l.source || d === l.target)
        return "link active";
      else
        return "link inactive";
    });
  });

  // Set the stroke width back to normal when mouse leaves the node.
  node.on('mouseout', function() {
    link.attr('class', "link");
  })
    .on('click', click);

  function click(d) {
    if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
      var inc = d.collapsed ? -1 : 1;
      recurse(d);

      function recurse(sourceNode){
        //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
        edges.forEach(function(l) {
          if (l.source.id === sourceNode.id){
            l.target.collapsing += inc;
            recurse(l.target);
          }
        });
      }
      d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
    }      
    update();
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light",
    "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  fill: black;
}
.node:active {
  fill: lightgray;
}
.node .text {
  fill: white;
}

.ORG .circle {
  fill: #1d3649;
}

.EMR .circle {
  fill: #b2d0f5;
  stroke: #5596e6;
  stroke-dasharray: 3px, 3px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.EMR .circle:hover {
  fill: #5596e6;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #eee;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link.active {
  stroke: darkblue;
  stroke-width: 4;
}

.arrow {
  fill: #666;
}

.arrow.active {
  stroke-width: 0 !important;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
.doubled {
  fill: red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```